# How do I match items from one table to other items in a 2nd table in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, `monsters` `items` and `joinedInfo`

I want to join `monsters` and `items` so that joinedInfo shows what items can be dropped by what monsters.

Example:

Monsters:

| ID | MonsterName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cow |
| 2 | Chicken |
| 3 | Goblin |

Items:

| ID | ItemName | MonsterForeignKey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bones | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | Feathers | 2 |
| 3 | Gold | 3 |
| 4 | Eggs | 2 |
| 5 | Cow hide | 1 |
| 6 | Dagger | 3 |

JoinedInfo:

| ID | MonsterName | ItemName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Goblin | Bones |
| 2 | Goblin | Gold |
| 3 | Goblin | Dagger |
| 4 | Cow | Bones |
| 5 | Cow | Cow hide |
| 6 | Chicken | Bones |
| 7 | Chicken | Feather |
| 8 | Chicken | Eggs |

Some items are unique to one monster and other items are shared with multiple monsters.

- Cow, chicken and goblin can drop bones.
- Chicken and goblin can drop coins.
- Only cow can drop cow hide.
- Only goblin can drop sword.
- Only chicken can drop eggs.

How do I associate different items to to the different monsters? Eventually there will be a lot more monsters and items right but now I just want to figure out how to associate them together.

An example I found on google I tweaked to fit what I thought would join them:

```
SELECT items.ID, items.ItemName, monsters.MonsterName, monsters.ID FROM items, monsters;
LEFT OUTER JOIN joinedInfo ON MonsterName.ID = joinedInfo.ID AND MonsterName.ID = items.MonsterForeignKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON group_elements.GroupID = groups.ID
```

I was hoping for something like this

JoinedInfo:

| ID | MonsterName | ItemName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Goblin | Bones |
| 2 | Goblin | Gold |
| 3 | Goblin | Dagger |
| 4 | Cow | Bones |
| 5 | Cow | Cow hide |
| 6 | Chicken | Bones |
| 7 | Chicken | Feather |
| 8 | Chicken | Eggs |

What I get on sqlfiddle:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752e35/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE monsters
    (`ID` int, `MonsterName` varchar(43))
;
    
INSERT INTO monsters
    (`ID`, `MonsterName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Cow'),
    (2, 'Chicken'),
    (3, 'Goblin')
;

CREATE TABLE items
    (`ID` int, `ItemName` varchar(9), `MonsterForeignKey` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO items
    (`ID`, `ItemName`, `MonsterForeignKey`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Gold', 3), 
    (2, 'Bones', 1),
    (3, 'Feathers', 2),
    (4, 'Cow Hide', 1),
    (5, 'Dagger', 3),
    (6, 'Eggs', 2)
;

CREATE TABLE group_elements
    (`GroupID` int, `ElementID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO group_elements
    (`GroupID`, `ElementID`)
VALUES
    (3, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT items.ID, items.ItemName, monsters.MonsterName FROM items, monsters
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752e35/3/0)**:

```
| ID | ItemName | MonsterName |
|----|----------|-------------|
|  1 |     Gold |         Cow |
|  1 |     Gold |     Chicken |
|  1 |     Gold |      Goblin |
|  2 |    Bones |         Cow |
|  2 |    Bones |     Chicken |
|  2 |    Bones |      Goblin |
|  3 | Feathers |         Cow |
|  3 | Feathers |     Chicken |
|  3 | Feathers |      Goblin |
|  4 | Cow Hide |         Cow |
|  4 | Cow Hide |     Chicken |
|  4 | Cow Hide |      Goblin |
|  5 |   Dagger |         Cow |
|  5 |   Dagger |     Chicken |
|  5 |   Dagger |      Goblin |
|  6 |     Eggs |         Cow |
|  6 |     Eggs |     Chicken |
|  6 |     Eggs |      Goblin |
```

**Query 2**:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN joinedInfo ON monsterName.ID = joinedInfo.ID AND monsterName.ID = items.MonsterForeignKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON group_elements.GroupID = groups.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752e35/3/1)**:

Comment: I don't think your question is completely clear, what is your table, data? and what is your desired output? where is the `joinedInfo` table in your fiddle?

Comment: I have three tables, monsters items and joinedInfo.

My data is a list of monsters in a video game and the items that drop when they are killed. My desired output was already posted in the body. I want to join monsters and items tables into joinedInfo table to show what items are dropped by what monsters when killed. The joinedInfo table is what gets created when I do the innerjoin as seen in Query 2.

Comment: So you have to join items and monster tables and produces result that looks like `joinedinfo` table?

Comment: Correct. I need to match each item to each respective monster that drops the specific item because not all monsters drop all items but some monsters share multiple items. Then I need to join them together into a single table called JoinediInfo so it displays what items are dropped by which monsters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `FIND_IN_SET` for getting your answer,
try this

```
SELECT m.`ID` AS monsterId, 
m.`MonsterName`, 
i.`ItemName` 
 FROM `monsters` m 
 JOIN items i 
 ON FIND_IN_SET(m.`ID`,i.`MonsterForeignKey`)
 ORDER BY m.`ID`
```

Comment: This accomplishes what I needed thank you

Answer (score 0):

With ID representing the name of the animal and MonsterForeignKey representing the item that can be dropped by that animal, an INNER JOIN to join the two tables by linking `t1.ID=t2.MonsterForeignKey` returns the following:

```
select t1.ID, t1.MonsterName, t2.ItemName from monsters as t1
inner join Items as t2 on t1.ID=t2.MonsterForeignKey order by id;

 id | monstername | itemname 
----+-------------+----------
  1 | Cow         | Bones
  1 | Cow         | Cow Hide
  2 | Chicken     | Feathers
  2 | Chicken     | Eggs
  3 | Goblin      | Gold
  3 | Goblin      | Dagger
(6 rows)
```

By using INNER JOIN, we are filtering so as to include the ID, Monster Name and the Item Name that can be dropped by the animal.

Since MonsterForeignKey contains this information, this is why we need to link this variable to the ID.

Comment: how do you join the `1,2,3` columns from `items`  table?

Comment: This is being joined with the ID in the Monsters table - Monsters is named t1 in the above clause and Items is named t2, hence the use of ```on t1.ID=t2.MonsterForeignKey```. The MonsterForeignKey is not actually displayed as a column in the result, but this is what is being used with ID to link the two tables together.

Comment: Oh no no, the id is stored as comma separated values in a single cell. You cannot directly join it

Comment: In the Monsters table? It is stored as a separate column - so I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say "you cannot directly join it".

Comment: Go to [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7be9294/2). There are two queries, you will know what I mean.